# Use UNIXTIMESTAMP with ummalqura-calendar Library

Tags: java, android, calendar, unix-timestamp, hijri

I am using [ummalqura-calendar](https://github.com/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar) to Show Hijri Date in my Android Application

am getting date from back end Service as UNIXTIMESTAMP, How can i use this format with the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unix time stamp (*seconds* since epoch), you should be able to just multiply the timestamp by 1000 to get milliseconds and use `setTime`;

```
Calendar uCal = new UmmalquraCalendar();
uCal.setTime(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000));
```

If you already have the timestamp in milliseconds, just leave out the multiplication.